# Color coding of LaTeX3 code

Tags: feature-request, markup, code, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible for the JavaScript syntax highlighter to be extended to color code LaTeX3 code? With the current color coding scheme the code is very difficult to follow.

Comment: LaTeX 3 code is hard to follow even with correct coding scheme ;-)

Comment: uhh... I can almost envision the horrendous regexps that'd take

Comment: @morbusg  At least if it highlights [\\a-zA-Z:_] it can immediately look better. It shouldn't be that hard to do. At the moment the commands look like a long train with only the first wagon painted:)

Comment: Yiannis: I was thinking about how to still have `_` as a reserved letter; i.e., support from the same regex file for both TeX and LaTeX3. (`/^(?=[^\\])[&_etc.]/` for reserved vs. `/^\\(?:[^\\])[\w_]*\b/]` for command names [or something along those lines]). I'm not sure how the unioning would handle that.

Comment: It really does come down to simultaneously supporting LaTeX2e and LaTeX3 syntax on the site; it's not really possible to distinguish between them without an explicit `LaTeX3` or `LaTeX2e` tag of some sort.

Comment: Related: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/168244)