# Syntax highlighting for LaTeX3?

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Two years ago, @YiannisLazarides asked if [Color coding of LaTeX3 code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2278/color-coding-of-latex3-code) could be added to the syntax highlighter of TeX.SE.

With posts using LaTeX3 code becoming be more and more frequent I would like to propose to re-open the request for some way to indicate LaTeX3 code and make it more readable on the site. Could a tag be added to somehow turn on proper coloring of LaTeX3 code?

Comment: From [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/168244): "... Please **DO NOT** ask if certain languages will be supported in the future. That is **not** a question we can answer because Stack Exchange does not maintain this highlighter. Visit [Google Code Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) for language support."

Comment: @PauloCereda To the reception please

Comment: @Werner sorry if this was the wrong place for this request. I'm quite willing to send the request to the Google Code Prettify project, but I am not able to make the needed RegEx'es to capture the LaTeX3 syntax. I was hoping someone at TeX.SE had the required knowledge and skills.

Comment: @MartinHeller: This *is* a good place to post it, but there would be nothing one can do to change this from here, as language support would have to be implemented network-wide. True, someone with the knowledge of the complete LaTeX3 language would have to write something up that could be implemented...

Comment: Prettify has been moved to GitHub -- that is to say, I'm working on a PR :)

Comment: If you know anything about prettify, some input would be appreciated :) 23 days and crickets. https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/370